# Возможно ли "виртуальное клонирование" в С++?

Tags: c++, gcc

Наткнулся в "More Exceptional C++" на информацию, что виртуальные методы могут вместо указателей на объекты базового класса возвращать объекты перегруженного класса. Решил попробовать смоделировать "самоопределяющийся" объект - с виртуальным методом, вместо указателя базового класса возвращающим указатель на объект производного, чтобы можно было вызывать функции, отсутствующие в базовом классе. Вот пример с "виртуальным клонированием":

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(){}
    virtual ~Base()=0;
    virtual Base*   clone()
    {
        qDebug()<<"Base clone";
        return 0;
    }
};

Base::~Base(){}

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived(){}
    virtual Derived*   clone()
    {
        qDebug()<<"Derived clone";
        return new Derived(*this);
    }
    QString derivedOnly(){return "derivedOnly";}
    virtual ~Derived(){}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Derived d1;
    Base *  b1=&d1;
    Base *  b2=b1->clone();     b2=b2;
    Derived * d2=d1.clone();    delete d2;
//  Derived * d3=b1->clone();   delete d3;
}
```

Так всё работает, и вывод qDebug показывает, что запускается клонирование производного класса. Однако, раскомментировав последнюю строку, при компиляции получаю сообщение об ошибке "invalid conversion from 'Base*' to 'Derived*' [-fpermissive]".

Выводы:

1. Очевидно, что компилятор (g++, Windows/MinGW) проигнорировал описание Derived * Derived::clone(), сгенерировав вместо него код для Base * Derived::clone().
2. Эту подмену транслятор сделал, никак меня не уведомив. Я рассчитываю получить указатель типа Derived*, а получаю Base* - и ничего об этом не знаю!
3. Я понимаю, для чего это сделано. Я мог бы написать что-нибудь типа b1->clone()->derivedOnly(), и транслятор не знал бы, допустима ли такая конструкция, так как статически неизвестно, будет ли при исполнении b1 указывать на Base или на Derived.

Вопросы:

1. Почему так происходит - является ли это частью стандарта (где можно посмотреть?) или самоуправством g++ (4.6.2)?
2. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы выдавался warning?
3. Ведут ли себя так же другие трансляторы?
4. Есть ли возможность решить изначальную задачу, то есть "развернуть" объект из указателя на базовый класс, не указывая, в какой именно класс мы его разворачиваем (т. е. без dynamic_cast'ов)?

Comment: а Вы с @nrw одногруппники? [Правильный подход к созданию копий][1]

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/407944/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Нет, конечно. Его запись я видел, и (чтобы народ не пугать) назвал функцию clone. Изначально она называлась getSelf, и возвращала просто this.

Comment: Да уж, ноосфера :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**О выводах**

Выводы неверные. Пункт 3 верный. Он же является ответом на Ваш вопрос.
А вот пункт 1 и, следовательно, 2 - неверные.

```
Derived* Derived::clone();
Base* Base::clone();
```

Какой из методов Вы бы выбрали, будь у Вас указатель на тип `Base*`?

**Ответы**

**1)** Вы же сами отвечаете себе на этот вопрос в выводе 3:

> статически неизвестно, будет ли при исполнении b1 указывать на Base или на Derived

Это приводит к тому, что компилятор использует статический тип объекта, то есть `Base*`. У объекта такого типа метод `Base* clone()` возвращает `Base*`, чтобы привести его к `Derived*` нужно явное преобразование.

Ссылка на стандарт: раздел **10.3.8**:

> [...] its result is converted to the type returned by the (**statically chosen**) overridden function (5.2.2)

**2)** Тут я поразмышляю о другом warning'е. Который не будет показан, если написать, например:

```
Derived* d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>( b1->clone() );
```

Явное преобразование `static_cast<Derived*>( b1->clone() )` это как бы уже warning. Страуструп пишет в "Дизайн и эволюция C++", что намеренно завел вместо лаконичного, но скрытного синтаксиса приведения типов C, громоздкий и неудобный, привлекающий внимание синтаксис приведения типов в стиле C++ (с `_cast<>`'ами). Кто Вам гарантирует, что `b1` всегда будет указывать на `Derived`-объект? Только Вы сами и гарантируете. За этот архитектурный "косяк" (см. п.4) Вы и расплачиваетесь `dynamic_cast`'ом. Или, если производительность важна, `static_cast`'ом, подкладывая себе [мину замедленного действия](http://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/113429/).

Относитесь к явным преобразованиям типов, как к warning'ам, ругающим Вашу архитектуру.

**3)** да. См. п. 1
Например, VS2013:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Base *' to 'Derived *'
      Cast from base to derived requires dynamic_cast or static_cast
```

**4)** Итак, Вы хотите реализовать виртуальный метод клонирования.

Сам метод реализован правильно, и работает правильно. Неправильно Вы используете результат клонирования - считаете, что там какой-то определенный потомок. На самом деле, имея указатель `Base*`, Вы можете полагаться только на интерфейс класса `Base`, никаких `QString derivedOnly()`.

Как же быть?

Вариант 0. Вы точно знаете, что `Base*` в данном контексте - это `Derived*`. Тогда Вы можете либо сразу указать тип `Derived*`, либо сделать `dynamic_cast`.

Вариант1. Код оперирует указателем `Base*` и неизвестно, на какой из наследников есть указатель: `Derived1*` или `Derived2*`. Вы клонируете объект, думая, что там `Derived1`, а на самом деле не он. Что тогда? Логика программы развалилась. Из-за того, что Вы полагаетесь на различный интерфейс сущностей, которые по контракту все имеют единый интерфейс `Base*`.

Comment: Ну вы загнули, однако, насчёт `static_cast`. В вашей статье, кстати, используется не он, а приведение типов в стиле C. Да и по поводу «архитектурных косяков» тоже. Распространённая ситуация — храним объекты в контейнере, потом получаем их оттуда и в зависимости от типа что-то делаем. 
Я бы добавил ещё, что сам `dynamic_cast` может быть плох, потому что он создаёт code smell, если проверяется принадлежность к нескольким классам. Иногда можно применить вместо него решение, использующее полиморфизм, а именно паттерн Visitor.

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/12261/atwice, спасибо!

"Какой из методов Вы бы выбрали, будь у Вас указатель на тип Base*?"

Я бы выбрал метод из vtable для моего объекта. Транслятор так и делает - вывод qDebug это подтверждает. По сути, все выводы верны, только формулировка первого неправильная: не "проигнорировал и сгенерировал", а "добавил преобразование из Derived* в Base*". И предупреждения не выдал.

По ответам:

1 - спасибо огромное, это то, что нужно. Заодно я и сам стандарт скачал.

2 - мимо. Всё и затевалось, чтобы обойтись без явных преобразований типа.

3 - спасибо.

Comment: 4 - Ну, вообще-то я хотел именно "разворачивалку" объекта из указателя на базовый класс в указатель на производный написать. Как dynamic_cast, но быстрый и не требующий явного указания имени производного класса. Но спрашивал о клонировании, так как исходную постановку вопроса счёл слишком наглой ;)

Вообще по размышлении я понял, что решаю не ту задачу. Надо думать не "как получить полный класс", а "как спроектировать, чтобы не требовались derivedOnly". Поищу в "Design Patterns".

Comment: > Я бы выбрал метод из vtable для моего объекта. Транслятор так и делает - вывод qDebug это подтверждает.
Не путайте время исполнения и время компиляции!
На этапе компиляции даже если есть указатель на vtable, то мы не знаем от какого класса подставится настоящаяя таблица. А значит не знаем точный тип возвращаемого значения. Знаем только тип, который указан в Base. А в Base указан Base*.
Еще раз! В этом месте никаких "добавил преобразование без предупреждения" нет!

Comment: Ну, в вопросе не указывалось, что выбрать метод я должен во время компиляции. Поэтому и ответил исходя из того, как понял.

А по поводу "добавил преобразование без подтверждения" я опираюсь на Вами же приведённый текст стандарта (10.3.8): "Когда перегружающая функция вызывается как окончательный перегрузчик (я не придумал лучшего перевода для слова overrider) перегруженной функции, её результат приводится к типу, возвращаемому (статически выбираемой) перегруженной функцией". То есть он вызывает мою функцию Derived::clone(), и приводит (=преобразует) результат к Base*.  Без предупреждения.